InDesign: Create a tag list and each tag with a background color
I am trying to achieve a tag list or keyword list with Adobe InDesign where each tag has a background color. The list of tags come from a csv file and I use data merge.
I attached an image of what I would like to do, I did not find a way of doing it yet.
Thanks a lot for your help


Not sure you can do this in a completely automated way, ID is not a website.
